# Can resource which requires asynchronous cleanup be constructed synchronously?

Tags: c#, async, resources

More specifically this applies only to resources which have asynchronous dependencies themselves (but I think that's majority of them).

Concrete example:

```
class Foo : IAsyncDisposable
{
    public ValueTask DisposeAsync { ... }
}

class Bar : IAsyncDisposable
{
    Foo _foo;
    public Bar(Foo foo)
    { 
        _foo = foo;
        // throw Exception(); 
    }

    public ValueTask DisposeAsync() { return _foo.DisposeAsync(); };
}
```

Can `Bar` be constructed synchronously? Let's try:

```
public void MakeBar(){
    Foo foo;
    try
    {
       foo = new Foo();
       return new Bar(foo);
    }
    catch
    {
        // cleanup foo. How?
        throw;
    }
}
```

We will either call `foo.DisposeAsync` synchronously, or we will leak resource which is not disposed.
Another option is to store `foo` for later and call dispose in async context (that's how DI containers work), but we need to await it anyway.

My conclusion is that unless I control the object and I can guarantee that construction does not fail, the construction should be asynchronous.

Is this conclusion correct?

By asynchronous construction I mean that function which creates it returns task (or value task):

```
public async Task<Bar> MakeBar(){
    Foo? foo = null;
    try
    {
       foo = new Foo();
       return new Bar(foo);
    }
    catch
    { 
        await foo?.DisposeAsync();
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you should explain what you mean by async construction: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8145479/can-constructors-be-async

Comment: @JimmyJames updated question with example.

Comment: Maybe this is relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22628087/calling-async-method-synchronously/22629216

Comment: @JimmyJames I think usually we do not want to do it, because we may deadlock

Comment: Could you elaborate on that point?

Comment: Did you look at the part that says "explicitly execute your async method in a thread pool thread and wait for it to finish"?  I'm not sure you need to wait for it to finish here.

Comment: @JimmyJames I guess that's ok if waiting synchronously is an option for us. Maybe turn it into an answer and we'll see further comments?

Answer (score 4):

Presumably `MakeBar` is part of a factory class, so you can dispose any unused dependencies asynchronously and await their disposal as part of the disposal of the factory.

```
class BarFactory : IAsyncDisposable
{
    protected readonly List<Task> _unused = new List<Task>();

    public Bar MakeBar()
    {
        var foo = new Foo();
        try
        {
            return new Bar(foo);
        }
        catch(SomeException e)
        {
            _usused.Add( foo.DisposeAsync().AsTask() );
            throw;
        }
    }

    public async ValueTask DisposeAsync()
    {
        await Task.WhenAll( _unused );
    }
}
```

Comment: You are not supposed to store `ValueTask`, you should either await it, or call `AsTask` or `Preserve`.

Comment: That's actually approach which is taken by IOC containers.
I think it's ok for IOC container to store `Foo`, because it could be reused by another class. 

In my example we want to dispose Foo as soon as possible, to not leak any resources (because we know the process failed). And storing instances for later creates new lifetime to manage.

Comment: @Shadow My code does not store any instances for later. It disposes the object immediately and stores the *task*, not the object. The only thing that is deferred is the `await`. If you need to guarantee complete and immediate disposal, you can dispose the factory.